# Excel errors vanish when I manualy enter formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, stockquotes

SO I'm trying to build a growth at a reasonable price screener, given a list of all stocks on the NYSE, that reads in and fills my column A with the ticker and B with the company name. The next columns use the SMF add-in from Yahoo and pulls data, such as the P/E and other metrics, off GARP (GROWTH at Reasonable price.) The formulas were built in the first row and dragged down over the rows of stocks. The issue that I am having is the formulas preform their job for the fist hundred or so stocks (rows), and then they all return error. However, if I scroll to a Blue chip stock and, in the formula box, click and press enter, the desired value will replace the error result.

Online I have found forms that suggest using arrays yet I cant seem to get an array to work, assuming my syntax would be =smfGetElementNumber(A4:A3298,#), where 'number' references a predefined function in the smf plugin and the data range is the spread of stock tickers.

Please advise as to why I receive this issue and what I can do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things you can try:

1. Make sure , `Formulas->Calculation Options->Automatic` is checked
2. Check the references of the cells in your formula i.e [Relative vs Absolute referencing](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-HP010342940.aspx)

## Edit:

If You have Calculation Options set to Manual and update the dependent cells follow this hack

- Select the cells that have issues and Select `Data->Text to Columns->Finish`

[image]